# Logging with Okta using Active Directory Employee Id

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, okta, okta-api

I am very new to OKTA. Currently I am engaged in a specific requirement where our on premises SharePoint 2013 Application is integrated with OKTA. As of  while trying to login to SharePoint the OKTA Login Screen appears which accepts **Ad UserName@Fully Qualified Domain Name** to sign in. But recently due to a changed requirement the business needs the Active Directory Employee Id to be used as UserName. I am unable to find any resources from Okta which can provide some insights into the requirement. Is this a aconfiguration change that needs to be done or this can be achieved through a API which plugs in the Employee Id into the Authentication Channel. Please help. I am very much stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an Okta SAML integration with SharePoint? Or have you imported the users directly into Okta?

Comment: @kevlened..SAML integration with SharePoint.. We have achieved the same with the help of Okta now.